Problem in finding relation between molarity and weight by weight percentage
While finding the relation I did the following steps:-
$\frac WW$% $= \frac{W_{solute}}{W_{solution}}\times100$ $.......(eq^n 1)$
(where both masses are in grams)
Since weight of solution can be written as $volume_{solution}\times density_{solution}$
(where  volume is in ml and density in g/ml)
and weight of solute can be written as $Molar mass_{solute}\times Moles_{solute}$
(where molar mass is in g/mol)
Plugging these values we found after our first equation in the  first equation we get
$\frac WW $% $= $ $M_{solute}\times n_{solute}\times100\over {V_{solution}}\times D_{solution}$
where M is molar mass of solute, D is density of solution, V is volume of solution(in ml ) and n is moles of solute
Since V is ml it can be written as $V\over 1000$ liters.
Now putting this in equation above we get
$\frac WW$% $= $ $M_{solute}\times n_{solute}\times100\over{V_{solution}}\times D_{solution}\times 0.001$ (now V is in liters)
$\frac WW$% $= $ $M_{solute}\times n_{solute}\times100000\over {V_{solution}}\times D_{solution}$
Since $Molarity$ $=$$ n_{solute}\over V_{solution}(in...liters)$
$\frac WW$% $= $ $M_{solute}\times M \times100000\over D_{solution}$
(where M is molarity of solute).
But the relation is not true so I was confused what was the mistake that i did while solving the problem?

Guides for formatting of chemical/mathematical formulas/expressions/equations: Basics / Detailed / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial

The mole and mol are the unit name and symbol, like the kilogram and kg, while the quantity name is the (molar) amount, like the mass.

$$C_\mathrm{A}=\frac{n_\mathrm{A}}{V}=\frac{m_\mathrm{A}}{M_\mathrm{A}\;V}=\frac{\rho_\mathrm{A}}{M_\mathrm{A}}=\frac{y_\mathrm{A}\;\rho}{M_\mathrm{A}}$$
$$\frac{w}{w}\%=y_\mathrm{A}\cdot100\%$$
$$\boxed{\frac{w}{w}\%=\frac{C_\mathrm{A}\;M_\mathrm{A}}{\rho}\cdot100\%}$$
Where:
$C_A$ = molar concentration of species A $(\pu{mol/L})$
$M_A$ = molar mass of species A $(\pu{g/mol})$
$\rho$ = density of solution $(\pu{g/L})$

You take mass concentration formally as fractional density. Interesting.

@Poutnik Indeed. It is analogous to its mole fraction counterpart in terms of molar concentrations: $x_A=\frac{C_A}{C}$

What I mean is that, IMHO, terms fractional mass/molar densities are very rarely used, in favour of respective concentrations.

I was able to prove the relation but when I did it in my class for the first time I used this approach. My question is what is the mistake here.

@Ur-Friend you forgot to convert the density units from $\pu{g/mL}$ to $\pu{g/L}$. In other words, your final expression needs to be divided by 1000.

@Ur-Friend It is good to explicitly include the used quantity units in expressions, where is a risk of unit mismatch. That prevents many errors.

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{w}{W}\%\right) &= \frac{\text{wt. of solute}\ (w_\ce{A})}{\text{wt. of solution}\ (w)}\times100 \\
C_\ce{A} &= \frac{n_\ce{A}}{V_\text{solution}\ \ce{(in m\ell)}}\times1000=\frac{w_\ce{A}}{M_\ce{A}}\times\frac{1000}{V_\text{solution}} \tag{1} \\
V_\text{solution} &= \frac{\text{wt. of solution}}{\ce{density of solution (in g/m\ell)}}= \frac{w}{\rho} \tag{2} \\
C_\ce{A} &=\frac{w_\ce{A}}{M_\ce{A}}\cdot\frac{\rho}{w}\times1000 \\
C_\ce{A} &=\left(\frac{w_A}{w}\times100\right)\cdot\left(\frac{10\rho}{M_\ce{A}}\right) \\
C_\ce{A} &= \left(\frac{w}{W}\%\right)\cdot\left(\frac{10\rho}{M_\ce{A}}\right) \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}$$
Rearranging equation $\eqref{3}$
$$
\left(\frac{w}{W}\%\right) =\frac{C_\ce{A}M_\ce{A}}{10\rho}
$$
